# Having trouble converting date String to NSDate

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm having trouble converting date String to NSDate

Here is my date string:

> Fri, 08 Apr 2016 16:59:35 +0300

Trying to convert to NSDate:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
let dateFromString : NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("Fri, 08 Apr 2016 16:59:35 +0300")
```

Return NSDate is:

> 2016-04-08 13:59:35 +0000

Timezone is wrong. Anyone can help with that?

Comment: Your code is fine and the output is correct and expected.

Comment: No, the time zone is not wrong. It's just that when you `print` a `NSDate` object, it always shows it to you in in the equivalent UTC/GMT/Zulu time zone. If you want to display a `NSDate` in your current time zone, use a `NSDateFormatter`'s `stringFromDate` (which I know sounds odd, given that you just used a formatter to convert that original string into a `NSDate` object).

Comment: For timezone you can use `NSTimeZone` in dateFormatter.

Comment: @Rob Thanks, now I understand.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"

NSTimeZone.setDefaultTimeZone(NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0))

let dateFromString : NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("Fri, 08 Apr 2016 16:59:35 +0300")!
```

Note that it does not account for DST.